# Keeping subview of UIScrollView from being effected by the scroll views content offset

Tags: ios, uiview

I have a UIView as a subview of a UIScrollView. The height of UIView is 50 and the height of the UIScrollView is 500.

I want to scroll from 50 to 500 in the scroll view while having the position of the UIView stay locked to the top of the scroll view. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Add a "Pin vertical space" constraint between the UIView and another view that is outside of the UIScrollView to lock the UIView in place when the UIScrollView is scrolling.

See here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-6_0/index.html

In above link, look at the notes for UIKit -> Autolayout support for UIScrollView

Copy pasting from the iOS release notes: "Note that you can make a subview of the scroll view appear to float (not scroll) over the other scrolling content by creating constraints between the view and a view outside the scroll view’s subtree, such as the scroll view’s superview"

Answer (score 0):

You could implement the `scrollViewDidScroll:` delegate method of `UIScrollView` and change the frame of the subview based on the current content offset of the scroll view.